# Horizontal Blanking Interval (Idling Time) optimization

Tags: streaming, capturing, image-sensors

I have questions regarding the time slot in-between two frames of video stream, i.e. Horizontal Blanking Interval (let's say HBI in the following), seen as Idling Time sometimes.
Considering a CMOS image sensor with Electronic Rolling Shutter, lighting is permanent)

**Is it possible to set the HBI to 0 (or very minimum) ? (increasing the VBI to respect frame rate)**

I understand the historical need (old screen display) to have an HBI (beam needed to come back to the beginning of the next line, but in the case of an image sensor case I "only" (if I can say so) see two cases where it is required:

- frame "real" size is too small, compared to the exposure duration requirement (=> virtually increasing line size by adding HBI).
- slot(s) may be needed to reconfigure some registers (Exposure, Gain, ...) of the image sensor, without stopping/restarting the stream
  Apart from these cases, I don't see some need to have it greater than 0. Yet it seems to me that there are always constraints on this parameter (i.e. it has to be greater than 0).

Linked to this point (understanding the possible constraints), **what is -- precisely -- included (meaning regarding low level) under the "readout" term ?**

I was not able to find it after lots of research.
My assumption/understanding is that it is the amount of time for transmission from the image sensor shift register to the outside world (likely PC)

Here-below is a schematic I have made trying to represent the video stream:
Legend is as follow:

- **$\color{black}{\text{RESET}}$** photosites well
- **$\color{gold}{\text{EXPO}}$** exposure time
- **$\color{red}{\text{CHARGE TRANSFER}}$** from photosites to shift register
- **$\color{darkblue}{\text{READOUT}}$** from shift register to the outside (through DVP, MIPI, ....)
- **$\color{black}{\text{HBI}}$***(white)* (horizontal blanking interval, idling time)
  [image]

*note: this schematic is on purpose not really well scaled, or even incorrect (see next question)
For example EXPO is very small, and probably there no sensor that allow such a small duration. But it is only for the sake of the point(s) I wanted to put the emphasis on.*

**Ultimately, how constrained is the flow of images, i.e. how much can they overlap each others?**

I don't see how the two green arrows could be not aligned (like in the schematic), I think it is not possible. But it seems to me that (at least) some sensor are able to readout multiple lines at once, even more some other readout "straight" (meaning line#, only then line#n+1, then ....) readout strategy, reading line specific order, ....
Is that correct ?